# How to connect to a Solaris Server to run shell commands from a PHP script?

Tags: php

I've got this PHP site which needs to connect to a Solaris Server to run shell commands (Execute shell script). Im using Apache. How do I connect to the server to run shell commands? Do i need to configure the Apache, & how? Am a newbie in PHP & Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to execute a command in php. Use ssh to connect a remote server and run shell commands.

Comment: Where do i use SSH to connect to the server? Inside my PHP script?

Comment: @tyc Something like this: `exec('ssh user@remote who');`